# Tighten vision metron aero brake lever

Tags: brakes

I don't see the screw to tighten on the [Vision Metron Aero Brake Lever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIPFq.png)
How do I access tightening bolt?

[image]

Comment: Which lever, exactly, do you have? The website link I edited in shows a different mounting system to the one in Kibbee's answer. If you could edit your question to show the exact lever you have that would be very helpful.

Comment: OK, to be clear - please upload a picture of the lever out of the handlebars. The answers so far have focused on the part inside the bars and at the end of the bars, so that's the part we need a photo of. But it's good that you're providing photos now, it means we might be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

perhaps [this video](https://youtu.be/9eCha9M6Llc?t=360) might help. I'm not sure if you have the same brake levers.  The part where he installs the brake levers is about 6 minutes in, which the link should go right to.

There's a small hex key bolt on the outside of the brake levers. You should be able to see it in the following picture, I have circled what I'm pretty sure are the screws you are looking for.

[image: Vision Metron Aero Levers]

The [installation instructions](http://www.visiontechusa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ZS005A-Vision_Aero_Brake_Lever_English_20110324_v11.pdf) linked to from the page you linked to shows the "fixing bolt" labeled as "3" in the following diagram

[image]

Comment: I have a Vision Metron Aero Brake Lever, no shifting on brake lever, it has no hex screw on the side.  Vision says to hold down brake lever and access socket with a 5 or 6 mm hex key.  I have tried that but socket seems to turn with no tightening. Lever is only 2 months old.

Comment: The second picture is directly from the installation instructions on the page you linked to.  This installation instructions are specifically for the brake lever only version as they only show the installation of the brake cable, and not for the shifter cable as it doesn't exist on this model.  In both cases the fixing bolt is in pretty much the same place. You should see the bolt, or the hole the both goes into.  Provide pictures of you specific brake lever showing both sides if none of these match you brake levers.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the expansion bolt setup, based on your comments to Kibbee's answer.

[image]

The arrow points to a conical head bolt with a 5mm hex hole up the middle. **Note that you're turning this bolt from "underneath" so you turn the opposite direction to what you expect.** Viz, clockwise to undo the bolt/remove the brake lever from the bike; and anti-clockwise to tighten the bolt/fix the lever into the handlebars.

This exploded view of a simliar system might help show what's happening:

[image] (via [Park Tool](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bar-end-shifter-service#article-section-1))

What I've done with those shifters in the past is grease the threads and conical surface on that bolt so it turns more easily and I'm less likely to end up with corrosion locking the whole thing in place (more likely with steel handlebars).

Comment: I don't seem to be able to access the 5mm allen bolt.  I have squeezed the brake lever but all I see is a small hole where the brake cable is coming in.

Comment: @bks can you please put a photo of your exact lever in your question? This guessing stuff is hard on everyone.

Comment: Note that the two image portray two different setups.  In the top image there is a lug on the lever body which locks the expansion wedge to keep it from turning separately.  If one uses your tape scheme then the screw is locked to the wedge and nothing will ever tighten.

Comment: My suspicion is that the bolt is tightened by using an Allen wrench through the end of the lever, into the threaded end of the bolt (with the lever depressed).  But I've never seen this specific lever before.

Comment: @bks I suddenly remembered the secret - you're accessing the wrong end of the bolt so you turn it backwards. I bet that is the problem.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'm kind of interested that the non-end bolt version seems to have a wee cap on the lever where you'd expect to push the allen key through if it had the 5mm bolt hole, but the one where you do that doesn't have the wee rubber cap. See Kibbee's photo... from the instructions that appears to be to insert the brake cable.

Comment: @Móż - Note that the two different levers are entirely different in how the actual lever meets the lever body.  I would guess that if you squeeze the lever on the OP's unit and look in the end of the lever body you will see a hole for an Allen wrench.

Comment: @DanielRHicks that is kind of the point of my answer, yes.